# Photon yield of NaI

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, radioactivity, experimental-technique, particle-detectors

We have to calculate the photon yield of the scintillator NaI. We have measured his pulse height spectrum but we have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone explain it?
The source that we used was Cs-137

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem years ago - the solution comes in two steps: quantum efficiency, and photo-electron yield. (Note - I am using "quantum efficiency" loosely: really the term should be "photon detection efficiency" which is a combination of the effects of photons leaving the site of the interaction and traveling to the photocathode, the conversion procdess in the cathode, the escape of the photoelectron, and its surviving the first dynode amplification process to produce an electron shower).

**Photo electron yield**

Step 1: find the number of photo-electrons generated. For this you need to know the single photoelectron gain of your sensor (I am going to assume you are using a PMT - photomultiplier - but the same is true for other devices). You need a very weak and reproducible light source - a heavily attenuated pulsed LED can do the trick. You want to be able to turn the pulse down to single digit photons.

The key insight here is that for a very low number of photons per pulse, the actual number of photoelectrons will follow a Poisson distribution - and the variance of a Poisson distribution is equal to the mean. Measure the variance of the observed signal as a function of input intensity, and plot one against the other for a number of values. You will get a straight line. From the slope of the straight line you can get the magnitude of the scale factor, which in turn allows you to turn the signal from the PMT into "number of photoelectrons detected".

Mathematically:

$$S = \alpha P$$

where $S$ = signal, $\alpha$ is the gain factor, and $P$ is the number of photoelectrons. If the variance $V$ of signal $S$ is plotted as a function of signal, then the expected relationship is

$$ \frac{V}{\alpha^2} = P $$

So when we plot $V$ against $S$, the slope is $\alpha$.

[image]

A second method of calibration is to do the same experiment, and measure the number of times that you see "zero" photons (in all these experiments, you need to trigger the data acquisition when the LED is pulsed, regardless of the observed signal). Then you can use Poisson statistics to determine the number of photoelectrons detected, since

$$P(0) = e^{-\lambda}$$

where $\lambda$ is the mean number of photoelectrons.

The next plot shows the result of these two methods plotted against each other: the agreement is really quite good. This is unpublished data - I can not give a reference.

[image]

**Quantum efficiency**

The second issue is then the conversion from photoelectrons to incident photons. This is a combination of photon collection efficiency (reflectors etc - typically very good) and quantum efficiency (QE - probability of photons being converted to amplified photoelectrons). The QE is extremely tricky to measure accurately, in part because it's a function of angle of incidence. Typically people will use a calibrated reference in order to make any progress - it's a very hard thing to do.

See http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/23.256593 for an example of the measurement of light yield of a scintillator, and [P. Eckert et al. / Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research A 620 (2010) 217–226](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.nima.2010.03.169) for a good description of the determination of absolute quantum efficiency.

Incidentally - the photon yield of NaI:Tl is a function of energy. Since the energy of the Cs-137 peak is far above the K edge of iodine, you have multiple Compton scattering events inside the scintillator before the energy is absorbed - and this means that depending on the path of an individual gamma ray, there will be some excess noise on the observed signal.

Answer (score 1):

You spectrum should show at least two easily identifiable features with known energy: the full absorption peak and the [Compton edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_edge). You may be able to get the escape peaks, too, but they are often hard to pick out of the background with NaI.

With these features you can identify a ratio 
$$
R = \frac{\text{(signal in your system)}}{\text{(energy deposited in the crystal)}} \,,
$$ 
(here I have assumed the simple proportional case). That's still not a raw photon yield, of course, because you still have to contend with a photon collection and conversion efficiency to worry about but you are often content with $R$.

If you have to isolate the contributions to $R$ you are going to have to pair different scintillators with different light collectors.

---

Finally, using only a single calibration source (Cs-137 in your case) limits your assumptions about the algebraic form of the efficiency curve (generally proportional or linear). More calibration sources are useful if you want to do a really good job of calibrating.